# Regex for Hex Digits

Tags: java, regex, hex

I'm very new to Regex so I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the following:

Regex to find Html style hex representation for color AND
How to make a regex to find gray hex codes, Such as #7C7C7C ?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using capturing group and backreference:

```
"#([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})\\1\\1"
```

Example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})\\1\\1");
String css = "#abcdef #7C7C7C #001122";

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(css);
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

output:

```
#7C7C7C
```

Comment: This pattern does not match colors like #FFFFff #fffffF. Most browsers accept these.

Comment: @neoexpert workaround  convert string to lower/upper case before match.

Comment: I use this one: "#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})\\b". It is nice, because it ignores invalid color codes like #ffff

Comment: @neoexpert, That pattern does not solve OP's problem. It can match non-gray color code.